# Using debugger swo on stm32

Tags: c++, c, stm32, jtag

As the title suggest I would like to use swo for debugging on an stm32F1 device without the use of st-link utils.I think I have flashed the code to send messages via swo on my chip but I can not establish a connection with the correct port as some tutorials suggested I use putty with the telnet port 2332 . 
Specifics about my configuration:[image: cubemx swo configuration]
Relative code on my main

```
    int _write(int file, char *ptr, int len)
{
    int DataIdx;
    for (DataIdx = 0; DataIdx < len; DataIdx++)
    {
        __io_putchar(*ptr++);
    }
    return len;
}
```

...

```
   int main(){
    while (1)
      {
        printf("Hi\n");
      }
}
```

I have seen some tutorials using eclipse configurations or st-link utils but I have a very custom toolchain (I use conan, obko cmake configurations https://github.com/ObKo/stm32-cmake , ocb and linux) for the sole purpose of using c++ 2017 and libraries like boost so I can not use st-link utils.

Comment: Try linking with rdimon.specs

Comment: @KamilCuk Semihosting is considered too slow for my application, can you elaborate a bit if I didn't get correct your point?

Comment: @KamilCuk Whith that it doesn't link it says I have multiple definitions of some secret functions _lseek `-specs=nosys.specs -specs=nano.specs  -specs=rdimon.specs`

Comment: And are you using `--whole-archive?` `-specs=nosys.specs -specs=nano.specs` cause you link twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with my configurations was that I didn't have a parser on my computer for the `ITM` messages so even after having the right configurations on the chip when I was opening the port to communicate with the chip my terminal was empty of messages . Hopefully I found this [very helpful parser on github](https://github.com/robertlong13/SWO-Parser) so all I had to do after compiling the program with the above configurations was to run   `openocd` with configuring two options about the frequency of the `f1` chip and the 
fact that `ITM` port was open (here is my `.cfg` file ):

```
source [find interface/stlink-v2.cfg]
source [find target/stm32f1x.cfg]
init
tpiu config internal - uart off 72000000
itm ports on
```

and on another terminal I runed the parser script from github `python3 swo_parser.py`

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable ITM port 0 (or another one) then output the chars using this port.

When it works you can wrap it into the printf

```
uint32_t ITM_SendChar (uint32_t ch)
{
  if (((ITM->TCR & ITM_TCR_ITMENA_Msk) != 0) &&      /* ITM enabled */
      ((ITM->TER & 1) != 0)   )     /* ITM Port #0 enabled */
  {
    while (ITM->PORT[0].u32 == 0)
    {
      __NOP();
    }
    ITM->PORT[0].u8 = (uint8_t)ch;
  }
  return (ch);
}
```

Comment: Thank you I up voted your answer as it helped a lot but this doesn't say anything about how to connect to the right port ,so I will do an answer myself including openocd configurations for the default port

Comment: line 4 & 5 checks if it is connected. Connection is just by setting those bits

Comment: I think this exact function is defined in cmsis headers file `CMSIS/Include/core_cm3.h:1698:26`  so it wassomething else not working